# Titanium textField stored as integer

Tags: javascript, titanium, textfield, appcelerator

I'm trying to store references to several textfields in a array. When I try to access the elements of the array, I get some integers instead of the textfield objects ! I can't figure out why this happens…

```
var textfields = [];
function doClick(e) {        
    var txtField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        value:"test"
    });
    textfields.push(txtField);
    $.index.add(txtField);

    for(var textfield in textfields) {
        console.log("stored value : "+textfield);
    }
}

$.index.open();
```

Output after three "clicks" :

```
[INFO] :   ---click---
[INFO] :   stored value : 0
[INFO] :   ---click---
[INFO] :   stored value : 0
[INFO] :   stored value : 1
[INFO] :   ---click---
[INFO] :   stored value : 0
[INFO] :   stored value : 1
[INFO] :   stored value : 2
```

When I stringify the whole array however, I see the textField IS inside, but I don't know how to access it.
Here is the array with two textFields inside :

```
[
   {
      "enabled":true,
      "selection":{
         "length":0,
         "location":0
      },
      "backgroundRepeat":false,
      "children":[

      ],
      "rect":{
         "height":45,
         "y":61,
         "x":137,
         "width":47
      },
      "value":"voilà",
      "visible":true,
      "size":{
         "height":45,
         "y":0,
         "width":47,
         "x":0
      },
      "keepScreenOn":false,
      "apiName":"Ti.UI.TextField",
      "maxLength":-1,
      "bubbleParent":true
   },
   {
      "enabled":true,
      "selection":{
         "length":0,
         "location":0
      },
      "backgroundRepeat":false,
      "children":[

      ],
      "rect":{
         "height":45,
         "y":107,
         "x":137,
         "width":47
      },
      "value":"voilà",
      "visible":true,
      "size":{
         "height":45,
         "y":0,
         "width":47,
         "x":0
      },
      "keepScreenOn":false,
      "apiName":"Ti.UI.TextField",
      "maxLength":-1,
      "bubbleParent":true
   }
]
```

From what I understand, textfield.value should work but it returns "undefined" since textfield itself is a number… How can I access the elements I stored in the array ?

Comment: Try calling textfield['value']

Comment: It's also undefined, but thanks for trying.

Comment: you should not stringify textfields! Just loop through them, and fetch the value

Comment: I just stringified the whole array to check it has not magically turned into a integers array… I guess I stop thinking pragmatically when stuck, but it was not intended to be kept !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for...in` is wrong... It should be:

```
for(var textfield in textfields) {
    console.log("textfield : "+textfields[textfield]);
    console.log("textfield : "+textfields[textfield].value);
}
```

`for in` sets the `key` in the `textfield`, not the element.

Look at the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in

An even better way to loop in Titanium (when using Alloy) is `underscore`

```
_.each(textfields, function(textfield){
    console.log('textfield value:' + textfield.value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the explanation. I should have looked it up though.

Answer (score 2):

Please try forEach instead for-in loop. See below code.

```
textfields.forEach(function(textField){
    console.log(textField.value);
});
```

Comment: Your solution is also working, thank you ! I accepted Rene Pot's answer since I am more comfortable with `for in` loop and he explained a bit.

Comment: No problem it's matter of preference. What matters at the end is that you should get the desired result.